# Android Convert List<String[]> to String[]

Tags: android

Android How to Convert `List<String[]>` to `String[]`.....

Comment: You can't do that. A `List<String[]>` is something that contains many `String[]`s. Unless you're trying to flatten the list and combine all your inner `String[]` elements into a single `String[]` array.

Comment: What a question? You are the winner of "Most impressive question". Give more details with your question to have good answers

Comment: What do you have, `List<String>` to convert to `String[]` or `List<String[]>` to convert to `String[][]`?

Comment: @Dante isn't then two problems? One easy (List<String> to String[]) and one more interesting (String[] to String)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    static String[] convert(List<String[]> from) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String[] strings : from) {
            Collections.addAll(list, strings);
        }
        return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }
```

Example use:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        list.add(new String[] { "one", "two" });
        list.add(new String[] { "three", "four", "five" });
        list.add(new String[] { "six", "seven" });
        String[] converted = convert(list);
        System.out.print(converted.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to convert a List< String> to a String[ ], you can use [List.toArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29)